# Easy Search of Road or Address in QGIS

Tags: qgis, address

Is there an easy way to search for a road name in a polyline layer in QGIS?  I'm looking for something like what ArcMap 10.1 has, just a basic search box where I can type in a name and have it give me a list of matches, then have the option to zoom to it, or highlight it, or something

Answer (score 4):

in attribute table, doesnt **Look For** option work for you?

[image: qgis]

or you can use [Find by Attribute](http://pyqgis.org/contributed/findbyattr.zip) plugin too.

> An update to the Find by Attribute plugin providing useful
>   functionality for finding and zooming to single or multiple features.

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 2):

If you uncheck the "Case sensitive" option at bottom of attribute table, write in the "Look for" space and select the field of interest, you can get coincident rows highlighted (If you know the exact word you can leave the "Case sensitive" option checked).

After that you can use "Show selected only" to view in screen only the rows that match with you criteria and copy to clipboard.

[image]

Later you can use the option "Zoom to selection" to view the elements in the map.